# Word2vec модель выводит ошибку на любое слово

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Использовал gensim и модели с [RusVectōrēs](http://rusvectores.org/ru/models/), но после загрузки на любое слово получаю ошибку:

```
>>> w = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format("/Users/andrey/Downloads/ruwikiruscorpora_rusvectores2.bin.gz", binary=True, encoding='utf-8')
>>> w["дом"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/andrey/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 576, in __getitem__
    return self.word_vec(words)
  File "/Users/andrey/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 275, in word_vec
    raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
KeyError: "word 'дом' not in vocabulary"
```

Comment: Всё правильно в словаре `w` нет ключа `дом`, о чем вам и говорит ошибка.

Comment: @Alban слово "дом" там есть, и естественно пробывал я не только слово  "дом"

Comment: @Andrey, а Вы уверены, что с этой библиотекой работают именно так? Что Вы ожидаете увидеть в выводе команды `w['дом']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не знаком с `gensim` и `word2vec` - поэтому детально и подробно ответить не смогу.

Используя [интерактивный Python (iPython) или Jupyter](https://ipython.org/) вы можете набрать имя переменной/объекта/функции и нажать `TAB` - это покажет вам все доступные методы и атрибуты:

```
In [23]: w.
       w.accuracy                w.load                    w.most_similar_cosmul     w.similar_by_word         w.wmdistance
       w.doesnt_match            w.load_word2vec_format    w.n_similarity            w.similarity              w.word_vec
       w.evaluate_word_pairs     w.log_accuracy            w.save                    w.syn0
       w.index2word              w.log_evaluate_word_pairs w.save_word2vec_format    w.syn0norm
       w.init_sims               w.most_similar            w.similar_by_vector       w.vocab
```

посмотрим что нам дает `w.vocab`:

```
In [28]: type(w.vocab)
Out[28]: dict

In [29]: [x for x in w.vocab.keys() if x.startswith('дом')]
Out[29]:
['дом_S',
 'домой_ADV',
 'дома_ADV',
 'домашний_A',
 'домик_S',
 'домовой_S',
 ...
```

т.е. `Word2Vec` хранит слова с указанием того чем это слово является (существительное, глагол, ...)

```
In [31]: w['дом_S']
Out[31]:
array([  4.13864665e-02,  -1.80019736e-02,   3.45242396e-03,   9.96965468e-02,  -2.70169564e-02,  -4.41602208e-02,   6.49831370e-02,   4.156
75081e-02,   6.94336072e-02,   3.49395089e-02,
        -6.00887947e-02,  -7.21584409e-02,  -2.55677663e-02,  -8.69021043e-02,  -6.61841631e-02,  -2.22225040e-02,  -1.22106038e-01,  -6.485
07327e-02,  -4.36170287e-02,  -1.36744939e-02,
         4.80352268e-02,   2.38850527e-02,   1.44935966e-01,   5.68681248e-02,   4.95017357e-02,  -4.18773070e-02,   2.75598951e-02,  -1.053
75908e-01,   5.70621006e-02,  -8.55170488e-02,

In [32]: w.most_similar('дом_S', topn=5)
Out[32]:
[('особняк_S', 0.7157765626907349),
 ('квартира_S', 0.6657882928848267),
 ('флигель_S', 0.6554150581359863),
 ('домик_S', 0.6489031314849854),
 ('коттедж_S', 0.6390868425369263)]
```